# Worksheet Collation Overflow issue

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to combine all data several worksheets into one, but I am getting an 'Overflow' error before it gets particularly far... Surely there is a better way of writing it to avoid this issue!

```
Sub collateSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim src As Worksheet
Dim LR As Integer
Dim LR2 As Integer

Set ws = Sheets.Add
With ws
    .Name = "Collated Data"
    .Range("1:1").Value = Sheets(2).Range("1:1").Value
End With
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Activate
    LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LR2 = Sheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If LR2 <> 1 Then
        For j = 2 To LR2
            LRinput = LR - 1 + j
            ws.Rows(LRinput).Value = Sheets(i).Rows(j).Value
        Next j
    End If
    LR = vbNull
    LR2 = vbNull
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Long` rather than `Integer` as the latter only goes up to about 32k https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long Am assuming that's the problem, though might be others.

Comment: dang that's the first time i've hit the limit on integer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are looping on new "Collated Data" sheet also

place it as the first sheet and itarate from sheet 2 on

also, you can avoid iterating through rows and copy/paste their value in one shot

finally loop through `Worksheets` collection, and avoid any possible Chart Sheet:

```
Sub collateSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long, LR2 As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets.Add(before:=Sheets(1)) ' place new sheet in first position
    With ws
        .Name = "Collated Data"
        .Range("1:1").value = Sheets(2).Range("1:1").value
    End With
    For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count ' loop from 2nd sheet on (thus avoiding "Collated Data")
        LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LR2 = Sheets(i).Cells(Sheets(i).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If LR2 <> 1 Then ws.Rows(LR + 1).Resize(LR2 - 1).value = Sheets(i).Rows("2:" & LR2).value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: where has Resize been all my life? Tanks!

Answer (score 1):

My code create a new sheet named "Output" and import all the data in.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub test()

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim wsNew As Worksheet
        Dim Lrow As Long
        Dim Excist As Boolean
        Dim SheetName As String

        SheetName = "Output"

        Excist = False

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            If ws.Name = "Output" Then
                Excist = True
                Set wsNew = ws
            End If
        Next

        If Excist = False Then
            Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
            wsNew.Name = SheetName
        End If

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            If ws.Name <> "Output" Then
                ws.UsedRange.Copy

                Lrow = wsNew.Cells(wsNew.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                wsNew.Range("A" & Lrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: this looks good but it uses copy & paste, and word on the street is that this is slower than the value = value method. So I've been looking for ways to avoid copy & paste, but when the dimensions of the range are variable, that's where I run into trouble, because I can't say ws1.Range("A1:A10").value = ws2.Range("A1:A10").value if it is going to change everytime. 

Luckily I can just copy the entire row in this instance, but I'm willing to bet there is a computationally faster solution... and it has something to do with Resize